# How to check if a column whether contains a specific element after grouping by?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to check whether the column `app` grouping by the column `user` contains a specific element, such as `b`.

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame({'user':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'app':['a','b','c','a','c','b','c']})
```

`Input:`

```
   app  user
0   a     1
1   b     1
2   c     1
3   a     2
4   c     2
5   b     3
6   c     3
```

`Expected:`

```
   app  user  contains_b
0   a     1           1
1   b     1           1
2   c     1           1
3   a     2           0
4   c     2           0
5   b     3           1
6   c     3           1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df['contains_b'] = df['user'].isin(df.loc[df['app'].eq('b'), 'user'].unique()).astype(int)
print (df)

   user app  contains_b
0     1   a           1
1     1   b           1
2     1   c           1
3     2   a           0
4     2   c           0
5     3   b           1
6     3   c           1
```

**Details**:

First filter by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) `(==)` column `app` and get all user rows:

```
print (df.loc[df['app'].eq('b'), 'user'])
1    1
5    3
Name: user, dtype: int64
```

For better performance use [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
print (df.loc[df['app'].eq('b'), 'user'].unique())
[1 3]
```

Then test `user` column for membership by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (df['user'].isin(df.loc[df['app'].eq('b'), 'user'].unique()))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: user, dtype: bool
```

And last cast to integer `True`s are `1`s and `False`s - `0`.

Answer (score 4):

#### `transform` with `any`

```
df.assign(contains_b=df.app.eq('b').groupby(df.user).transform('any').astype(int))

  app  user  contains_b
0   a     1           1
1   b     1           1
2   c     1           1
3   a     2           0
4   c     2           0
5   b     3           1
6   c     3           1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
df['contains_b'] = df.groupby('user').app.transform(lambda x: x.isin(['b']).any()).astype(int)

    user app contains_b
0   1    a   1
1   1    b   1
2   1    c   1
3   2    a   0
4   2    c   0
5   3    b   1
6   3    c   1
```